# Bugs in navbar when scroller

Tags: jquery

I made a navbar that changes size dynamically when scroller, however I'm having some problems, the image is being cut, in firefox the size for the top navbar does not work.

jQuery

```
num = $('.topbar').offset().top;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.topbar').stop().animate({height: 34}, 200);
    } else {
        $('.topbar').stop().animate({height: 92}, 200);
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rj2k535z/)

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? Just the navbar to change size when scrolled, but not the image?

Comment: This is how jquery makes it animation - by setting overflow:hidden. Move image outside of the `.topbar`

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanted was for the image to not get cut off but while the navbar changes size as you scrolled, then you are pretty close. Just move your image tag out of the `<div>`.

```js
num = $('.topbar').offset().top;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.topbar').stop().animate({height: 34}, 200);
    } else {
        $('.topbar').stop().animate({height: 110}, 200);
    }
});
```

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

body{
    height: 2000px;
}

.topbar{
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
}

#img {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topbar"></div>
<div id="img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tsiftgN.png" />
</div>
```

(Tested in Chrome and FF.)